# login to a website with Python

Tags: python, authentication, web, urllib2, cookielib

I am trying to login to a website using Python.
I have the following code and it really works when I login to a website.

```
import ClientCookie, ClientForm
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup  

cookies = ClientCookie.MozillaCookieJar()

fp = ClientCookie.urlopen("http://www.renrendai.com/loginPage.action?error=false")

forms = ClientForm.ParseResponse(fp)  
fp.close()  
form = forms[0]  
form["j_username"]  = "userid"   
form["j_password"] = "password"  
fp = ClientCookie.urlopen(form.click())  
fp.close()


userHomePage_href = "http://www.renrendai.com/lend/userHomePage.action?userId=114590"  
userHomePage_doc = ClientCookie.urlopen(userHomePage_href)  
userHomePage_soup = BeautifulSoup(userHomePage_doc,fromEncoding="gb18030")
```

but if I use it to login to [another website](http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx), it doesn't work.
I have this source from the site:

```
<input name="txtUserName" type="text" value="tinkei" id="txtUserName" class="lsls" onfocus="changeborder(this)" onblur="changeborder2(this)" style="height:26px;width:280px;border-width:1px; border-color:LightGray;" />
<input name="txtPassword" type="password" maxlength="50" id="txtPassword" onfocus="changeborder(this)" onblur="changeborder2(this)" style="height:26px;width:280px;border-width:1px; border-color:LightGray;" />
<input type="image" name="btnLogin" id="btnLogin" src="http://static.ppdai.com/skin/images/login_n_button.gif" alt="登录" style="border-width:0px;" />&nbsp;
```

Is it because of the value of 'btnLogin'?

Comment: *I have the following code and it really works(...)* No, it can't work because you use `ClientCookie` which is nowhere defined... One of the worst things you can do when asking is to post some made up code and tell people it's working code then you're using.

Comment: For the above reason, this is slightly unclear - however, for one, you need to change the form names - substitute "txtUserName" for "j_username" and "txtPassword" for "j_password" in the case of the second website. You will likely need to do this for every website; most use different (albeit often only slightly) form field names.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have missed some of the code (import ClientCookie, ClientForm). For sure I have changed "txtUserName" for "j_username" and "txtPassword" for "j_password" and it doesn't work. I just want to know why the code can work on the first website but doesn't work on the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [requests](http://python-requests.org) lib for that, it is very easy.

```
import requests
payload = {'txtUserName': 'value1', 'txtPassword': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx", params=payload)
>>> r.text
THE_RESPONSE
```

Please try the example i posted, just change value1 to the username and value2 to the password.

[example url](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: `requests` is pretty awesome, but does this answer the question?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I am discouraged to the problem.

Comment: @Shimon I tried it on my college's course website. It didn't work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think I may have a similiar problem, but with a different site.
I saw this:

[Logging in to a web site with Python (urllib,urllib2,cookielib): How does one find necessary information for submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887345/logging-in-to-a-web-site-with-python-urllib-urllib2-cookielib-how-does-one-fi)

> Look at what data is sent in dev tools of your browser. It doesn't matter if it's aspx or >not, or at least shouldn't. As far as you concerned it's just a http service. Make sure >that you fake headers as well, some websites check them (user agent, referer, etc). I >also suggest to use requests module. – gatto Apr 8 at 19:41
>
> Thanks for the heads up. I'll look further in to faking the headers. As far as the >rest of my input values am I missing anything? – arete Apr 8 at 19:43
>   1
>
> Well, for one you should parse the form (use lxml) to get the values, because they >are most likely dynamic, so hardcoded values won't do. And I would keep everything, even >empty hidden inputs, just to be sure. Ok, so the process is load page - parse and get the >form - post form data with cookies and headers. – gatto Apr 8 at 19:52

For http://www.ppdai.com/login.aspx

I suppose they would mean this part

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/     wEPDwUKMTM0MDY0ODA1OQ9kFgICAQ8WAh4EVGV4dAXuATxzY3JpcHQgc3JjPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS1hbmFseXRpY3MuY29tL2dhLmpzIiB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPjwvc2NyaXB0PjxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT0idGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0Ij50cnkge3ZhciBwdCA9IF9nYXQuX2dldFRyYWNrZXIoIlVBLTM2MzU2NjQtMSIpO3B0Ll9zZXREb21haW5OYW1lKCcucHBkYWkuY29tJyk7cHQuX3RyYWNrUGFnZXZpZXcoKTt9IGNhdGNoKGVycikge308L3NjcmlwdD5kGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBQhidG5Mb2dpbkPZsS5trJ5Fyz2xtZdq47OvRkst" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQKRr4PqCgKl1bKzCQK1qbSRCwKC3IeGDAKQo8KrDbSMQeI06gCgwhXGUNBJw4I0qMjg" />
```

I hope you manage to figure and solve your problem.